# Displaying attribute table on top in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I would like to pin (fix) the opened attribute table to the QGIS window or display the table on top. The attribute table is opening as another window (and it is possible to open the same attribute table as new window many times- it is unusable).

I cannot work with the map content and at the same time see the attribute table. Is there any solution?

Comment: I discovered that getting a second monitor screen solves many similar problems ;)

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 27):

You can set the *Attribute Table* to be in a **dock window** which allows you to 'fix' to certain positions.

You can set this by going to:

```
Settings > Options > Data Sources > Open attribute table in a dock window
```

In versions prior to QGIS 3.4 you will need to restart QGIS for this to take effect:

[image: Options]

Now when you access the *Attribute Table*, it may appear at the bottom. Just drag this towards the top:

[image: Drag interface]

And it should be 'fixed':

[image: Result]

Comment: @SÚSPk - Most welcome ;)

Comment: In QGIS 3.4 you actually don't even need to restart QGIS. Just enable the Option described by Joseph and the next time you open an attribute table it is shown in a dock bar. At least on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There's a "Dock Attribute Table" button on the extreme right of the attribute table toolbar. Clicking it will dock/undock the attribute table. I use QGIS 3.28.1 Firenze.

[image]